# How is award score calculated in Battlefield 3?

Tags: pc, battlefield-3

I've done a little bit of searching but haven't found much beyond some speculation. Does anyone know how the award score is calculated? I've been MVP a number of times but I don't think I've ever been the top award score before (came close but not quite) so it makes me wonder what I'm not doing in regards to that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Award Score is the total of the points received through awards in that round.  Awards include ribbons, medals, attachment unlocks, and service stars.

The round you get a vehicle or class service star (10,000 pts) you'll most likely get Top Award Score.

Comment: Ahh, okay. I mean, that seems obvious now, but I guess I thought it factored in other stuff since when I played a medic on big ticket maps I could sometimes win by 5-10K points and still not get the top award score. This would probably explain why I seem to get closer to the top when I play multiple classes, as some of those long term bonuses and unlocks probably coincided. Thanks.